# How can I differentiate artist name / track name in meta data?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, metadata

Currently in my iOS app, I am fetching the meta data for the `currentTrack` to a `UILabel` that displays what is now Track Info.
Currently it displays: Now Playing:   (This is my label)-> ***Artist Name - Song Name***

The artist name is always separated by a hyphen, how can I break it apart so that I can have a `UILabel` with the artist name, and another `UILabel` with the track name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can find location of hyphen with code  `[string rangeOfString:@"-"].location`
and then you may have sub strings with `[string substringToIndex:20];` and there is `[string substringFromIndex:21]`

Comment: Thanks for the response, I can tell this will fix the problem,  
    
`NSUInteger *xxx = [_trackName rangeOfString:@"-"].location;` 
 now when I do this, I get a yellow warning saying "Incompatible integer to pointer conversion initializing 'NSUInteger *'(aka 'unsigned long*') with an expression of type 'NSUIneger' (aka 'unsigned long')
    
and 
    
    `NSString *xxxx = [_trackName substringToIndex:xxx];`

Gives me another yellow warning that says "Incompatible pointer to integer conversion sending 'NSUInteger*' .... " any idea on how I can fix this? thanks

Comment: Also, now that I have the artist name alone, how do you suggest i get the track name alone?

Comment: After doing lots of testing, my app is crashing on commercials, Xcode highlights the line of code that says `NSString *xxxx = [_trackName substringToIndex:xxx];` (xxx being the number of characters since it will not always be 20) and gives me the following in my console log `'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSCFString substringToIndex:]: Index 2147483647 out of bounds; string length 17'`